# group by week, but new group if it falls into next month

Tags: mysql

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how I would do this.

I have daily (most days) invoice data that I need to group in buckets of weeks. However if the week goes into the next month I need the bucket to only have the amount of days in it that fall in the current month, and then the next bucket would start on the 1st - the next saturday. so that the next full week starts again on sunday.

Right now we just don't group it at all, and just export by day which gives us ~60 million rows for the rolling 2 years (it is more complex than the example as it also is split by item and customer). This then gets imported into our demand planning software which has both a weekly and monthly model. It has no problem dumping them into the correct buckets when it is by day.

However I would like to decrease this ~60 million rows as we are running into some time constraints. But it still has to accurately work with both the weekly and monthly models the data gets imported into.

How can I group this way?

```
Example Data set
+------------+------------+
| date       | sales      |
+------------+------------+
| 2014-06-22 | 100        |
| 2014-06-23 | 200        |
| 2014-06-24 | 300        |
| 2014-06-25 | 150        |
| 2014-06-26 | 170        |
| 2014-06-27 | 210        |
| 2014-06-28 | 220        |
| 2014-06-29 | 120        |
| 2014-06-30 | 110        |
| 2014-07-01 | 190        |
| 2014-07-02 | 210        |
| 2014-07-03 | 100        |
| 2014-07-04 | 140        |
| 2014-07-05 | 150        |
| 2014-07-06 | 130        |
| 2014-07-07 | 420        |
| 2014-07-08 | 310        |
| 2014-07-09 | 290        |
| 2014-07-10 | 180        |
| 2014-07-11 | 140        |
| 2014-07-12 | 210        |
+------------+------------+


Expected Result:
+------------+------------+
| date       | sum(sales) |
+------------+------------+
| 2014-06-22 | 1350       |  7 days in group
| 2014-06-29 | 230        |  2 days in group
| 2014-07-01 | 790        |  5 days in group
| 2014-07-06 | 1680       |  7 days in group
+------------+------------+
```

EDIT:

We came up with a working solution. Feel free to improve on it if wanted, or not.

```
SELECT DATE(IF(
        MONTH(DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)) = MONTH(`date`)
        , DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)
        , DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
    )) AS datekey
    , SUM(val) AS valsum

FROM tmp.testdata

GROUP BY IF(
    MONTH(DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)) = MONTH(`date`) -- If the closest previous Sunday from date falls within the same month as the date...
    , DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY) -- ...use the date of the closest previous Sunday as the key...
    , DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-01') -- ...otherwise use the 1st of the month the date falls in as the key (since that must mean the date falls in that opening partial week).
)

ORDER BY datekey
```

Thanks all! We combined some of this together and ended up with:

```
SELECT MIN(`date`) AS datekey
    , SUM(val) AS valsum

FROM tmp.testdata

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U'), MONTH(`date`), YEAR(`date`) 

ORDER BY datekey
```

OR in the case we ALWAYS want the bucket to be sunday or the 1st (for instance when not all days have invoices) we combined my solution with the one here, since the group here was faster

```
SELECT 
    DATE(IF(MONTH(DATE_SUB(`date`,
                    INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)) = MONTH(`date`),
            DATE_SUB(`date`,
                INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY),
            DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-01'))) AS datekey,
    SUM(val) AS valsum
FROM
    tmp.testdata
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U') , MONTH(`date`) , YEAR(`date`)
ORDER BY datekey
```

Comment: We do not currently group it at all. However, we came up with a solution that works. Anyone can feel free to find a better option.

Comment: I found a nice easy way to do this for you using DATE_FORMAT to get the Sunday week below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to think about...

`calendar` is a simple table of dates...

```
 SELECT MIN(dt),YEARWEEK(dt),MONTH(dt) FROM calendar WHERE dt BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' GROUP BY YEARWEEK(dt),MONTH(dt);
 +------------+--------------+-----------+
 | MIN(dt)    | YEARWEEK(dt) | MONTH(dt) |
 +------------+--------------+-----------+
 | 2014-01-01 |       201352 |         1 |
 | 2014-01-05 |       201401 |         1 |
 | 2014-01-12 |       201402 |         1 |
 | 2014-01-19 |       201403 |         1 |
 | 2014-01-26 |       201404 |         1 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-02-01 |       201404 |         2 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-02-02 |       201405 |         2 |
 | 2014-02-09 |       201406 |         2 |
 | 2014-02-16 |       201407 |         2 |
 | 2014-02-23 |       201408 |         2 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-03-01 |       201408 |         3 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-03-02 |       201409 |         3 |
 | 2014-03-09 |       201410 |         3 |
 | 2014-03-16 |       201411 |         3 |
 | 2014-03-23 |       201412 |         3 |
 | 2014-03-30 |       201413 |         3 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-04-01 |       201413 |         4 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-04-06 |       201414 |         4 |
 | 2014-04-13 |       201415 |         4 |
 | 2014-04-20 |       201416 |         4 |
 | 2014-04-27 |       201417 |         4 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-05-01 |       201417 |         5 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-05-04 |       201418 |         5 |
 | 2014-05-11 |       201419 |         5 |
 | 2014-05-18 |       201420 |         5 |
 | 2014-05-25 |       201421 |         5 |<-- No overlap
 | 2014-06-01 |       201422 |         6 |<-- No overlap
 | 2014-06-08 |       201423 |         6 |
 | 2014-06-15 |       201424 |         6 |
 | 2014-06-22 |       201425 |         6 |
 | 2014-06-29 |       201426 |         6 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-07-01 |       201426 |         7 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-07-06 |       201427 |         7 |
 | 2014-07-13 |       201428 |         7 |
 | 2014-07-20 |       201429 |         7 |
 | 2014-07-27 |       201430 |         7 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-08-01 |       201430 |         8 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-08-03 |       201431 |         8 |
 | 2014-08-10 |       201432 |         8 |
 | 2014-08-17 |       201433 |         8 |
 | 2014-08-24 |       201434 |         8 |
 | 2014-08-31 |       201435 |         8 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-09-01 |       201435 |         9 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-09-07 |       201436 |         9 |
 | 2014-09-14 |       201437 |         9 |
 | 2014-09-21 |       201438 |         9 |
 | 2014-09-28 |       201439 |         9 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-10-01 |       201439 |        10 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-10-05 |       201440 |        10 |
 | 2014-10-12 |       201441 |        10 |
 | 2014-10-19 |       201442 |        10 |
 | 2014-10-26 |       201443 |        10 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-11-01 |       201443 |        11 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-11-02 |       201444 |        11 |
 | 2014-11-09 |       201445 |        11 |
 | 2014-11-16 |       201446 |        11 |
 | 2014-11-23 |       201447 |        11 |
 | 2014-11-30 |       201448 |        11 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-12-01 |       201448 |        12 |<-- Overlap
 | 2014-12-07 |       201449 |        12 |
 | 2014-12-14 |       201450 |        12 |
 | 2014-12-21 |       201451 |        12 |
 | 2014-12-28 |       201452 |        12 |
 +------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: This definitely put us on the correct path! Thanks. We overthought the problem and assumed it needed a much more complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT min(date),sum(sales) FROM sales GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```

Update: WEEKOFYEAR() will use the MySQL calendar which starts the week on a Monday.  So I found you can use DATE_FORMAT to get the week number starting with Sunday.

```
SELECT min(date),sum(sales) FROM sales GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%U'), MONTH(date);
```

Comment: Devon, thanks for this. Much simpler that what we came up with. I am not sure why I didn't think of grouping by the week BEFORE the month! However @Strawberry was a couple min quicker and his also makes sure the date in the result is the first date of the set.

Comment: @iMakeWebsites      
 
Group by will automatically sort by the column ASC, so it will always show the first date in the set

Comment: It isn't though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fac64/2 compared to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fac64/3/0

Comment: @Devon If it ain't in the SELECT, don't put it in the GROUP BY (and vice versa). To do otherwise is a recipe for disaster!

Comment: @iMakeWebsites you are right, I had thought MySQL would automatically sort date by ASC but apparently min(date) is necessary.

Comment: @Strawberry, that is not true.  There is no need to put the date_format() and month() in the select if you are not going to use for anything but grouping.

Answer (score 0):

We came up with a working solution.

```
SELECT DATE(IF(
        MONTH(DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)) = MONTH(`date`)
        , DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)
        , DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-01')
    )) AS datekey
    , SUM(val) AS valsum

FROM tmp.testdata

GROUP BY IF(
    MONTH(DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY)) = MONTH(`date`) -- If the closest previous Sunday from date falls within the same month as the date...
    , DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(`date`) - 1 DAY) -- ...use the date of the closest previous Sunday as the key...
    , DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-01') -- ...otherwise use the 1st of the month the date falls in as the key (since that must mean the date falls in that opening partial week).
)

ORDER BY datekey
```

Comment: I haven't studied it, but this still *looks* 'over thought' !!